# Error instantiating function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying the below simple thing to exercise the behavior of ADL

```
 namespace test{
   struct S{ public: s():a(10){} int a;};
   template<typename T>
   void fun(S o){
       T a{};
       std::cout<<(a+o.a)<<"\n";
   }
 }

 int main(){
     test::S  A;
     fun<int>(A);
 }
    error1: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
       fun<(int)>(A);
    error2:'fun’ was not declared in this scope
       fun<int>(A);
```

I am not sure about the first error(has it anything to deal with C++ vexing parse?) and for the second error since I've passed the argument of type `S` I believe that the ADL will consider `S` and its associated `namespace test` but not sure why I am getting `'fun’ was not declared` error.

Answer (score -1):

You placed fun<> in the test-namespace.

So call it with test::fun

Comment: Good attempt, but I think you missed the point of the question. There is a feature in C++ called ADL which would render this unnecessary, and the question is why ADL is not being triggered in the given code.

Comment: @Tomas Dittmann i appreciate your answer but i have came across this    "ADL proceeds by looking up the name in namespaces and classes "associated with" the types of the call arguments.The precise
definition of these associated namespaces and associated classes is given later, but intuitively they can be thought as
being all the namespaces and classes that are fairly directly connected to a given type."

Comment: Ahh I've never heard of ADL. Just reading about it right now. Learning by giving false answers...

Comment: @TomasDittmann well it happens :)